# Extract XML file from a PDF/A

Tags: java, pdf, xml

Do some java APIs exist that allow me to extract an XML file from a [PDF/A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A) in a Java?

Citing Wikipedia:

> PDF/A-3 allows embedding of any file format such as XML, CAD and others into PDF/A documents.